# Copy data from excel, and append it to an existing txt file

Tags: excel, vba, notepad

I'm trying to construct a macro which will copy data from excel and append it to an existing .ini file. what my macro is doing is opening the file (success), but overwriting the existing data in the file (wha wha) with the data in the cells A1, A2, A3 and A4 (yay). However, it is also adding the data in quotes.

```
Sub SimpleVBAWriteToFileWithoutQuotes()

    Open "C:\ABC\XYZ\CustomerCodes.ini" For Output As #1
    Write #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Write #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    Write #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
    Write #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A4")
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "Print" instead of "Write".
And Use "Append" instead of "Output".

```
Sub SimpleVBAWriteToFileWithoutQuotes()

    Open "C:\ABC\XYZ\CustomerCodes.ini" For Append As #1
    Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
    Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A4")
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you going to append data?

Comment: perfect, thx so much

Sub SimpleVBAWriteToFileWithoutQuotes()

        Open "C:\abc\xyz\CustomerCodes.ini" For Append As #1
        Print #1, vbNewLine; ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
        Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
        Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A4")
        Close #1

End Sub